# Multiple Layers Of <svg> polygons - Not Working

Tags: html, svg, polygon, layer

How can I add multiple layers of SVG polygons in the same SVG? For example, I have a drawing of a car (see snippet) over here, what if I want to add a window on it? If I write the new window markup below the car markup (see snippet) it is not visible. If I write it above the car markup is overwritten.

```html
<svg heght="100" width="100">
<!--bil-->  
<polygon points="0,100 0,70 5,65 20,65 30,40 70,40 80,65 95,65 100,70 100,100 90,100 80,90 70,100 30,100 20,90 10,100" style="fill:#777; stroke:#444; stroke-width:3px;">
  
<!--window-->  
<polygon points="30,30 50,30 50,50 30,50" style="fill:blue; stroke:#444; stroke-width:3px;">  

</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SVG you must terminate elements properly either with /> or a closing tag e.g. `</polygon>`

The html parser is parsing your current markup as nested polygons which is not allowed.

Your window's not in the right place but at least it's visible now.

```html
<svg heght="100" width="100">
<!--bil-->  
<polygon points="0,100 0,70 5,65 20,65 30,40 70,40 80,65 95,65 100,70 100,100 90,100 80,90 70,100 30,100 20,90 10,100" style="fill:#777; stroke:#444; stroke-width:3px;"/>
  
<!--window-->  
<polygon points="30,30 50,30 50,50 30,50" style="fill:blue; stroke:#444; stroke-width:3px;"/>  

</svg>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!